# Need replacement for deprecated arrays in error handling

Tags: c, linux, error-handling

I am modifying an old code, where it uses the deprecated `sys_errlist` and `sys_nerr` which are deprecated. Can someone tell me its replacement?

Also it will be great, if someone tells us about its functionality.

Here is the code:

```
37 static const char *
38 stringErrorReport(void)
39 {
40 #if ( defined(sgi) )
41         return strerror(oserror());
42 #elif ( defined(_AIX) )
43         return strerror(errno);
44 #else
45         if ( errno > 0 && errno < sys_nerr )
46                 return sys_errlist[errno];
47         else
48                 return "Unknown error.\n";
49 #endif
50 }
```

Let me know how to replace the deprecated `sys_nerr` and `sys_errlist[ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is a wrapper around strerror(), and tries to supply it's own replacement on systems where it assumes strerror()  is not available. If even sys_errlist and sys_nerr are not available, it fails. But it has at least tried ...

Comment: Can you please suggest it's replacement?

Comment: Especially how to check the range `errno > 0 && errno < sys_nerr`

Comment: It is just an array of strings (the textual representations of the constants in errno.h) It may or may not exist. The system headerfiles may or may not publish the declarations. If your system has strerror() in it's library, then it will have this table stored somewhere. It may or may not be visibel to you. (but you could always query it by calling strerror() from inside a loop, which is rather silly) Obviously, if the identifier sys_nerr (the table size) is not visible to your program, you can not test against it.

Comment: @wildplasser: too bad there isn't a way to upvote user screen names. Rete cool :)